# Boundary properties of some class of domains.

Tags: general-topology

Assume that $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain (open and connected). Suppose that $\partial\Omega$ has no isolated points (in $\partial\Omega$).

1 - Can I conclude that for each $p\in \partial\Omega$ there is $r>0$ such that the set $V_r=B(p,r)\cap\partial\Omega$ is connected?

2 - Can I conclude that for each $p\in \partial\Omega$ there is $r>0$ such that the set $V_r=B(p,r)\cap\partial\Omega$ is pathwise connected connected?

It seem to me that 2 is true, however, until now I got no idea to how to tackle this problem. Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is no. Consider
$$(-1,1)\times(0,1/2) \cup (-1,0)\times(0,1)\cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (2^{-2\,n} , 2^{-2\,n+1}) \times (0,1).$$
This should give you a comb, which is denser on one side.
Now consider $p = (0,1)$.

Comment: "the comb and flea"